# SQL statement in getting available equipment from stock

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table `equipment` with columns `name`, `description`, `status`

This is how my table looks like when I display all rows:

```
id  name      description   status
1   shovel    shiny shovel     1
2   shovel    shiny shovel     1
3   shovel    shiny shovel     0
4   hammer    big hammer       1
5   hammer    big hammer       0
```

This is the SQL statement I have right now:

```
SELECT equipment.name, equipment.description, COUNT(*) AS stock 
FROM equipment 
GROUP BY equipment.name
```

and it shows the following:

```
name    description   stock
shovel  shiny shovel    3
hammer  big hammer      2
```

What I want is to display another column showing the number of equipment that has a status of 1

```
name    description   stock  available
shovel  shiny shovel    3       2
hammer  big hammer      2       1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there: all you need is to sum up the status fields, like this:

```
SELECT 
    equipment.name, 
    equipment.description, 
    COUNT(*) AS stock, 
    SUM(status) as available
FROM equipment 
GROUP BY 
    equipment.name,
    equipment.description
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here (that will work in SQL Server and MySQL) is to use conditional `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`

```
    SELECT ..., SUM(WHEN CASE status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as available
```

If `status` can be only `1` or `0` then you can just total it:

```
    SELECT ..., SUM(status) as available
```